# SSHFS Permission Denied to symbolic link

Tags: symbolic-link, remote-access, sshfs

I can mount a remote directory to `/home/user/mnt` and can see symbolic links via `ls` of that directory, but I cannot r,w, or x the links. I mount using the code below, using RSA key pairs for automatic authentication.

```
$ sshfs my.server.ip:/remote/dir /home/user/mnt
$ ls -alh ~/mnt/file.txt -o allow_other,follow_symlink,uid=1000,gid=100
-rwxr-x---. 1 user users 1.6K Mar 22 8:00 /home/user/mnt/file.txt
$ cat ~/mnt/file.txt
#Some Text
```

The remote folder is mounted without error. I can list and read the file `file.txt` as expected.
When I try to ls and read `file_symlink.txt` I get:

```
$ ls -alh ~/mnt/file_symlink.txt
-rwxr-x---. 1 user users 1.6K Mar 22 8:00 /home/user/mnt/file_symlink.txt 
$ cat ~/mnt/file_symlink.txt
cat: /home/user/mnt/file_symlink.txt: Permission Denied
```

I can see it, but am denied permission.

I have tried many different `sshfs` options. Same behavior when I try running  via `sudo` also.

*An inconsistency to me is that `ls -alh file_symlink.txt` shows the symlink as a regular file*, rather than as a link. I think this is a result of the `follow_symlink` option, but when I mount without this option, I can still read the original `file.txt` as before, but when I go to access `file_symlink.txt` I get these results:

```
$ sshfs my.server.ip:/remote/dir /home/user/mnt -o allow_other,uid=1000,gid=100 
$ ls -alh ~/mnt/file_symlink.txt
ls: cannot read symbolic link /home/user/mnt/file_symlink.txt: No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user users 11 Mar 22 8:00 /home/user/mnt/file_symlink.txt
$ cat ~/mnt/file_symlink.txt
cat: /home/user/mnt/file_symlink.txt: No such file or directory
```

**`ls` first says the link doesn't exist, but then lists it, huh?**

If anyone knows enough about `sshfs` to clarify the behavior I am seeing, that would be awesome! Thanks!

I am also open to other methods of remote mounting drive

versions:
Fedora 23 4.4.3-300.fc23.x86_64
SSHFS version 2.5
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
fusermount version: 2.9.4
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19